# What does it mean to have a stationary value for a Volume curve? In real-world as well as math terms?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am a bit confused as to what it means to have a stationary value for, say, a volume equation.

For example, given the following cone:
[image]

Our equation is $$ V = \frac{\pi}{3}(225h - h^3)$$

I have found the derivative to be:
$$\frac{dV}{dx} = \frac{\pi}{3}(225 - 3h^2)$$

and the stationary point to be $5(3)^\frac{1}{2}$.

Now what does this mean?
I tried substituting 9 and 7 (above and below the stationary value), but I'm getting values for V both above and below V at $5(3)^\frac{1}{2}$.

So how is it a max/min point?

Comment: Not every stationary point is a max or min point. Then again, in the given problem we clearly have $V=0$ at $h=0$ and at $h=15$ and positive $V$ inbetween, so that by continuity a max point must exist, and if there is only one stationary point in $[0,15]$, it must be a maximum (as also witnessed by $V''$). Check your $V(7)$ and $V(9)$ values again

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi%2F3%28225x-x%5E3%29+where+x%3D7%3B5sqrt3%3B9 You've made an arithmetic error

Answer (score 1):

With
$$ V(h)=\frac \pi3(225h-h^3),$$
we have
$$ V'(h)=\frac\pi3(225-3h^2)=\pi(75-h^2)$$
and
$$ V''(h)=-2\pi h.$$
So we have stationary points at $h=\pm5\sqrt 3$, where only the positive value makes senses geometrically. But at positive $h$, clearly $V''(h)<0$ so that this stationary point is a strict local maximum. This is also the global maximum on the interval $[0,15]$ of feasible heights (as the boundary points $h=0$ and $h=15$ clearly do not lead to a maximum).

For convenience, note that
$$ V(7)=\frac\pi3\cdot 1232\approx 1290$$
$$ V(9)=432\pi\approx 1357$$
$$V(5\sqrt3)=250\sqrt 3\pi\approx 1360$$